# Handle SIGBUS ERROR ANDROID

Tags: java, android, sigbus

I am running a piece of code on android where I am getting the following error in the logcat.

> A/libc(18317): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0x5 in tid 18317 (com.test.1234)

I want to catch or resolve this error.